# Problem with filepath and rendering a stargazer table

Tags: r-markdown, rendering, filepath, stargazer, data-import

a newbe here.

I'm writing an essay in Rmarkdown and I want to render a PDF. When I try to import an excel sheet with the commands:

`dat1 <- read.xlsx("Seminararbeit.xlsx", 2L)`

and then create a table with stargazer, I keep on getting this Error:

Error in basename(filePath) :
unable to translate 'my-file-path-goes-here' to native encoding

It looks like the table is actually created with stargazer, but it doesn't show up when I knit the file. I tried to Reinstall R and Rstudio (I believe I have the newest version of both) but nothing worked. Is the file path too long? I have a MacOS, is that the problem?

Please help, it's driving me nuts!

Comment: The file has to be in the SAME root directory as the .rmd, also are you sure you loaded the package that has `read.xlsx()` in your Rmarkdown file? There can be issues if you are saving your .rmd and file on a network drive/external drives

Comment: Ah, that must have been it. I had my folder saved on microsoft onedrive. When I saved the project on my computer it worked. Thanks!